# question on nested while-for loop for polling aws S3-glacier restore

Tags: amazon-s3, nested-loops, aws-cli

I am trying to write a polling script that checks AWS S3 glacier for restoration status of objects every 60 minutes and then emails the user upon successful restoration (*Note: I am not showing the email component here*).

I have this nested while-for loop - in this code below, the job exits after the `for` loop is completed.

What could be wrong here? Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

file=$1   # single column file of S3 objects in a bucket
BUCKET=$2 # aws s3 bucketname

expected_num=$( wc -l $file | awk '{print $1}' )
echo "EXPECTED = $expected_num" > expectedNum.txt

while true
do
    for object in `cat $file`
    do
        echo "Checking S3 restoration $object"
        aws s3api head-object \
            --bucket $BUCKET \
            --key $object >> output_restore.txt
        echo "Done checking $object"
    done

queuelength=$( grep -c 'expiry-date' output_restore.txt )

if [[ "$queuelength" -ne $expected_num ]]; then
    echo "DELETING output_restore.txt"
    rm -f output_restore.txt
else
    echo "$NOW\tJobs completed:$queuelength"
    break
fi
sleep 60m
done

CURRENT="$(TZ=EST5EDT date +'%d-%b-%Y_%H%M')"
echo -e "$CURRENT\tcompleted"  > job_completed.txt
```